# Jira Custom Release Notes: Velocity if(..) Statements and Returned Values from Macros

Tags: jira, velocity

I have been experimenting with Jira's custom release notes feature, which requires writing a custom .vm file.  This is my first time working with Velocity and would greatly appreciate a hand with this minor issue:

I have a simple macro that checks is an `$issue` has a custom field called `For Release Notes` and gets its value.  Based on this value, I want Velocity to either output the issue summary, or skip it.

The problem is that even though the macro is returning `true` or `false`, I cannot get the `if()` statement to properly process the value.

Macro:

```
#macro(getForReleaseNotes $issue $customFieldManager)
    #set ($customFields = $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjects($issue.project.getLong("id"), $issue.issueType.getString("id")))
    #set( $retVal = "false" )
    #foreach($customField in $customFields)
        #if($customField.name.equals("For Release Notes"))
            #if($customField.getValue($issue)) #set( $retVal = "true" ) 
            #end
        #end
    #end
    $retVal
#end
```

HTML:

```
#foreach ($issueType in $issueTypes)
    #if($issueType.issues.size() > 0)
        <h2>$textUtils.htmlEncode($issueType.name)</h2>
        <ul>
        #foreach ($issue in $issueType.issues)
            #set( $tester = "#getForReleaseNotes($issue $customFieldManager)" )
            #if($tester == "true")
                <li>[<a href='$requestContext.canonicalBaseUrl/browse/$issue.key'>$issue.key</a>] - $textUtils.htmlEncode($issue.summary)</li>
            #else 
                <li> Value for macro: #getForReleaseNotes($issue $customFieldManager), $tester </li>
            #end
        #end
    </ul>
    #end
#end
```

I have tried a number of combinations within the `if()`, from `if( $tester.equals("getForReleaseNotes(..))" )`, to simply `if( "getForReleaseNotes(..) )`.

Now, the macro actually works and returns `$retVal = false` (or is it `$retVal = "false"` and does that make a difference?) when the issue does not have this property/the property is set to `false`.  The Macro will likewise return `true` if otherwise.  The issue is simply getting the `if(..)` statement to properly evaluate, because as of right now it says everything I pass into it is `false`, and issues never get printed.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this problem, though I do not believe it to be the most efficient because it requires looping through the list of issues twice.

The first loop checks if there are issues of the given issue type, and if any of those issues are marked as "For Release Notes."

If the first loop does find an issue marked For Release Notes, it moves to the second loop.  The second loop then pulls out the details of all the issues within that issue type that are marked For Release Notes.

NOTE: I added another field called "Release Note," so users have more control over what appears in the generated release notes.  If the field is not set, it defaults to using the issue summary.

```
#if($issueType.issues.size() > 0)
        #set($flag = "")
        #foreach ($issue in $issueType.issues)
            #set ($customFields = $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjects($issue.project.getLong("id"), $issue.issueType.getString("id")))
            #foreach($customField in $customFields)
                #if($customField.name.equals("For Release Notes"))
                    #if($customField.getValue($issue))

                        #if($flag==$textUtils.htmlEncode($issueType.name))

                        #else                       
                            <h2>$textUtils.htmlEncode($issueType.name)</h2>
                            #set($flag = $textUtils.htmlEncode($issueType.name))
                        #end

                    #end
                #end
            #end
        #end

        ## Go through the list again, displaying all issues that are "for release notes."
        <ul>       
        #foreach ($issue in $issueType.issues)
            #set ($customFields = $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjects($issue.project.getLong("id"), $issue.issueType.getString("id")))
            #foreach($customField in $customFields)
                #if($customField.name.equals("For Release Notes"))
                    #if($customField.getValue($issue))

                        ## If the issue has the "Release Note" field set, use that, otherwise use the summary
                        #foreach($customField in $customFields)
                            #if($customField.name.equals("Release Note"))
                                #if($customField.getValue($issue))
                                    <li>[<a href='$requestContext.canonicalBaseUrl/browse/$issue.key'>$issue.key</a>] - $textUtils.htmlEncode($customField.getValue($issue))</li>
                                #else
                                    <li>[<a href='$requestContext.canonicalBaseUrl/browse/$issue.key'>$issue.key</a>] - $textUtils.htmlEncode($issue.summary)</li>
                                #end
                            #end
                        #end

                    #end
                #end
            #end
        #end
        </ul>       
    #end
```

Answer (score 0):

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html has some examples of conditions in Velocity, and as you found out, they're not entirely obvious.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that, thanks for sharing the link.  For anyone else taking on a similar project, I would also recommend checking out the Jira issue api: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/issue/Issue.html

Answer (score 0):

Create the following macro and simply call it from whatever place in your vm file where you want to include the issue summary.

```
#macro( myMacro )
#set( $customFieldObj   = $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName('For Release Notes') )
#set( $customFieldValue = $issue.getCustomFieldValue($customFieldObj) )
## next line only makes sure the 2 variables are not null
#if( $customFieldObj && $customFieldValue )
## now output the issue summary
$issue.getSummary()
#end
#end
```

According to the [API](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/latest/com/atlassian/jira/issue/CustomFieldManager.html), getCustomFieldObjectByName will return the 1st custom field object with the give name, so if you have more than one custom field called 'For Release Notes', you wanna try the method getCustomFieldObject and pass the Long id of the field as a parameter.